# Upper Triangular Matrix in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Is there a way I can perform a faster computation of upper triangle matrix in scala?

```
/** Returns a vector which consists of the upper triangular elements of a matrix */   
def getUpperTriangle(A: Array[Array[Double]]) = 
{
    var A_ = Seq(0.)
    for (i <- 0 to A.size - 1;j <- 0 to A(0).size - 1)
    {
        if (i <= j){
            A_ = A_ ++ Seq(A(i)(j))
            }
    }
    A_.tail.toArray
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about faster, but this is a lot shorter and more "functional" (I note you tagged your question with `functional-programming`)

```
def getUpperTriangle(a: Array[Array[Double]]) = 
   (0 until a.size).flatMap(i => a(i).drop(i)).toArray
```

or, more or less same idea:

```
def getUpperTriangle(a: Array[Array[Double]]) =
   a.zipWithIndex.flatMap{case(r,i) => r.drop(i)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are three basic things you can do to streamline your logic to improve performance:

- Start with an empty `Seq`, so you don't have to call `Seq.tail` at the end. The `tail` operation is going to be `O(n)`, since the `Seq` factory methods give you an `IndexedSeq`
- Use `Seq.:+` to append a single element to the `Seq`, instead of constructing a `Seq` with a single element, and using `Seq.++` to append two `Seqs`. `Seq.:+` is going to be `O(1)` (amortized) and quite fast for an `IndexedSeq`. Using `Seq.++` with a single-element sequence is probably still `O(1)`, but will have a good bit more overhead.
- You can start `j` at `i` instead of starting `j` at `0` and testing `i <= j` in the body of the loop. This will save `n^2/2` no-op loop iterations.

Some stylistic things:

- It's best to always include the return type. You actually get a deprecation warning without it.
- We use lowercase for variable names in Scala
- `0 until size` is perhaps more readable than `0 to size - 1`

---

```
def getUpperTriangle(a: Array[Array[Double]]): Array[Double] = {
  var result = Seq[Double]()
  for (i <- 0 until a.size; j <- i until A(0).size) {
    result = result :+ a(i)(j)
  }
  result.toArray
}
```

Comment: I made some updates to the answer. You can also pull `A(0).size` out of the loop so you don't end up evaluating it n times.

Comment: You might also experiment with a single loop over the outer dimension of your array, and using `Seq.takeRight` along with `Seq.++` instead of looping over the inner dimension. I don't know if this approach would be faster; you would have to profile it.

Comment: Swapping the `for` (which will translate to `map`) for a `while` loop will also  speed things up.

Comment: Er, "which will translate to `foreach`". Also, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22631952/21755